# python + sqlite: How to use Order by for column with special letters?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to use `order by` to sort one of the column. This column, lets say its name is ColA, contains many **special letters**. Here is an example what ColA looks like:

```
ColA
Abc
D6
(8)
-s
'st
9-57
6s
A&C
5
Über
ру́сский
W/WO
```

I tried with the following codes.

```
import sqlite3

# Connect
WorkingFile = "C:\\test.db"
con = sqlite3.connect(WorkingFile)
cur = con.cursor()

# Sort data by ColA
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ColA ASC;")
print "sorted"
con.commit()

#rename the table:
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE MyTable RENAME TO TempOldTable;")

#Then create the new table with the missing column:
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE MyTable
            (WorkingID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT,
             ColA TEXT,
             ColB TEXT,
             ColC TEXT);
             ''')

#And populate it with the old data:
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO MyTable (ColA, ColB, ColC)
            SELECT                  ColA, ColB, ColC
            FROM TempOldTable;''')

#Then delete the old table:
cur.execute("DROP TABLE TempOldTable;")


# Finish
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

Here I was tring to make a new table, to define ColA to `TEXT` datatype, and copy the sorted data into it.

But it gives me no change to the database file.

Well, I adimit ColB and ColC contain also such kind of special letters.

But I think the programming idea is not wrong. So what am I doing wrong? Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: *Every* letter is a special snowflake. And what exactly is wrong with ORDER BY?

Comment: @CL. The code gives me no error message. But the data was not sorted. It's like the code has done nothing.

Comment: @CL. What do you mean with snowflake? You cannot see them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SELECT statement does not modify the database.

To reorder the table, you must sort the rows when you actually write the new table:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT               ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM TempOldTable
ORDER BY ColA;
```